# UITableView with multiple datasource

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a ViewController that needs to use 2 `UITableViews`.
1 is always showing, while the other will show up as a popup after you click on a button on the view.

Typically I set the delegate and `datasource` to the File's Owner. However, since 1 of the `UITableViews` is in a popup, I'm not sure how to best tackle this.

e.g how do I tackle this part `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;`

Please advice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should have instance variables for both table views declared in your controller:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
{ 
  UITableView *mainTableView;
  UITableView *popupTableView;
}
```

In each data source or delegate method, you can check which table view is being passed by the caller:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  if(tableView == mainTableView)
  {
    // Code to create and return a main table view cell
  }
  else if(tableView == popupTableView)
  {
    // Code to create and return a popup table view cell
  }
}
```

Comment: I was just about to type the exact same thing.  +1